# SQL Server backup missing identity column

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I've just restored a backup of a database onto a different server instance, only to find the identity columns are missing from tables.

Can anyone suggest a reason why this would be?

Is there a way to take a backup and leave the identity columns behind?

Google has left me answer-less.

Thanks,
Steve.

Comment: Missing means what ? The new Identity is more than 1000 ? if Yes, this is normal behavior.

Comment: The only way this can happen is if the backup was made before these identity columns existed. Typically we see such misunderstandings when a backup file contains multiple backups.

Comment: Hi Ahmed, Thanks lots for responding :) the identity columns literally didn't come across into the new restored database on the different server instance. When I do a sp_help TABLE-NAME, they aren't listed in the list of columns.

Comment: Hi SMor, thanks to you also, for responding ... that is an interesting suggestion, I will check the .bak file to see if it contains multiple backups.

Comment: Follow on question, is there any "permissions" or "role" thing that would prevent me from seeing the identity columns? Like, could it be possible that they are actually there, but the user I am using can't see them? I am using the user I used to restore the backups to run sp_help TABLE-NAME.